# Multiple Google Analytics code for url under same domain

Tags: google, google-analytics, url, tracking

I have one domain: `www.example.com`, and `www.example.com/sales`. The analytic code on both urls are different.

So when I login to my Google account it displays two separate analytic accounts. on `www.example.com/sales` I have a banner linked back to `www.example.com`.

I clicked that banners and I am sure there are other people have clicked the banner as well. but when I check the analytic of `www.example.com`, I don't see any thing come from my `example.com/sales`. I assume analytic on both urls are working, but why it doesn't track the visit from `/sales`. any idea??

Answer (score 2):

You need the same code across every page of your website for it to work properly. Once you are logged in you can drill down to see the traffic data of individual pages, and more. Typically the code is put right before the closing head tag.

Comment: "put right body the tag" - where? The [current recommendation](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_id=ad&answer=1008080) is to put the code immediately before the closing `</head>` tag.

Comment: Yeah that's right. Edited my post to be more clear.